# Github Pull Webhook with PHP - Apache permissions

Tags: php, git, bash, apache, github

I'm setting up my server to listen to a webhook which is currently

```
shell_exec('git pull 2>&1');
```

Receiving and executing is working fine, except the to get it to actually replace files I need to give www-data (apache debian) permission to write all the files/folders on my webserver, right?

Currently I'm getting this as a result (no write permissions)

```
Updating 115da6c..9e82ef0
error: unable to unlink old 'example-path/html.html' (Permission denied)
```

What are the security implications of giving www-data permission to write files, and is this the right choice or am I doing things all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another ways to achieve what you want:

1. **sudo**. Configure `sudo` to run the command passwordless and run `shell_exec('sudo git pull 2>&1');`.
2. Create a **setuid wrapper** that runs `git pull` and run `shell_exec('git_pull_suid_wrapper');`.